# How do i customize an riscv Rocket core?

Tags: github

I have downloaded Rocket core and performed all the necessary steps given in the github but i don't know how do i configure the rocket core?

Can anyone help me out with this?

I tried this cd rocket-chip/vsim
             make -j16 CONFIG="Example"
but don't know what it means

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow community. Please read [Welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Answer (score 1):

"Example" is just an example. There are many different configurations for different RISC-V repository. For example, BOOMConfig, SmallBOOMConfig, MegaBOOMConfig and others are supported by BOOM.

You may check the ***src/main/scala/Configs.scala*** to select the configuration you want.